# Trying to make a JFrame with a JPanel containing two JButtons

Tags: java, user-interface

I am a beginner here and I am trying to make a GUI that will display two buttons, addCard and deleteCard. However, the compiler is showing errors, and I cannot seem to find the error. Thank you in advance!

```
package studyfast;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Scratch{
    JFrame projectFrame = new JFrame();
    projectFrame.setSize(1000, 600);
    projectFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panelEditCard = new JPanel();

    JButton addCard = new JButton();
    JButton deleteCard = new JButton();

    panelEditCard.add(addCard);
    panelEditCard.add(deleteCard);

    projectFrame.add(panelEditCard);
    projectFrame.setVisible(true);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Scratch();
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors?
You need to give a few more details, if you want, that somebody helps you.

Comment: The majority of my errors are syntax errors

Comment: @Yousaf already answered your question ;)
But read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), befor you ask next time. It helps to verify your problem, if it is more complex.

Comment: @GAlexMES i agree with you that OP needs to provide more details but in this case, problem was obvious, so i just answered it.

Comment: @Yousaf that shouldn't be a reproach to you, sorry if it seems like that.

Comment: This is my first time posting a question on this site. I'll read it. Thanks!

Comment: @GAlexMES i know it wasn't a reproach. I agree with you that OP has provided no details of the errors. Everything's cool !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your code inside the `Scratch` class inside a `constructor`

```
package studyfast;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Scratch 
{
    JFrame projectFrame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panelEditCard = new JPanel();
    JButton addCard = new JButton();
    JButton deleteCard = new JButton();

    public Scratch()
    {
        projectFrame.setSize(1000, 600);
        projectFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);   

        panelEditCard.add(addCard);
        panelEditCard.add(deleteCard);

        projectFrame.add(panelEditCard);
        projectFrame.setVisible(true);
      }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       new Scratch();
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why you moved the button initialization inside the constrcutor, but leaving the JFrame and JPanel ilitialization outside?

Comment: @GAlexMES i forgot to move it outside the constructor. i just moved it outside the constructor. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Why might someone move the button initialization outside the constructor?

Comment: @AndyHou if you declare `JFrame` or `JButton` objects inside a constructor, you won't be able to access them outside that constructor, Their scope will be limited to that constructor in which they are defined.